# Could not add custom domain to recreated Azure Web Static app

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-webapps

I added my custom domain to Azure app service and then deleted this resource from Azure.
After I wanted to add same custom domain to Azure Web Static App but getting this error :

Could not add custom domain. Please ensure the custom domain is not linked to another app or that a previous implementation is not still being cleaned up.

What I'm doing wrong ?

[image]

I did these steps :

- removed CNAME from domain registrator and added new on pointed to Azure
- deleted App Service and cleaned up Custom domain
- waited 3 days because of Azure cache

Comment: Can you check do still see the deleted custom domain and web app is showing still under your subscription's resources? and also can you check is this custom is tagged to any other app.

Comment: I deleted app service and everything related to this. No tagged to any app

Answer (score 0):

I have an Azure App service where Custom domain is added.

[image]

When I tried to add the same domain to Azure Static WebApp, got the below error.

[image]

- In `App Service Domains` => `Manage DNS Records` =>`Record Set`, we need to have a new Record Set mapped to Static Web App.
  [image]

[image]

- It takes few hours for the new record set to get reflected.
- Able to add the same domain to Azure Static Web App without any issues.
- Enter the `record set` name and `Validate`.
  [image]

[image]